# How to resolve this

Tags: python

```
import gym
Streets = gym.make(“Taxi-v3”).env
Streets.render()
```

I wrote the code above but all I’m getting is an error in the render part. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Could you include the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

You create a new Taxi environment, but didn't get the initial state. So maybe try like this:

```
import gym
Streets = gym.make(“Taxi-v3”).env
Streets.reset()
Streets.render()
```

Comment: I’m getting AssertionError